# smtp protocol wont send email

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

Due to the new Google security requirements, I am trying to send an email from an asp.net application using smtp.freesmtpservers.com, it should be a free application testing service that does not even require authentication

This is my code:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add(email);
mail.From = new MailAddress("noreplay@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "new password ";
mail.Body = rand.ToString();

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Host = "smtp.freesmtpservers.com";
smtp.Port = 25;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Timeout = 60000;`
```

This is the error I get:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
> properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
> failed because connected host has failed to respond

I have tried adding:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

but nothing works.

Comment: Hopefully, there's no SMTP server without proper authentication. This will cause a lot of spamming. Do you have documentation about this SMTP server?

Comment: only this: https://www.wpoven.com/tools/free-smtp-server-for-testing

Comment: Looking at that site it looks like they don’t actually _send_ the email, they just ‘capture’ it and you can view it on the site. Are you sure that’s what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this first:

```
try
{
    var fromAddress = new MailAddress("no-reply@somedomain.com", "Robot");
    var toAddress = new MailAddress("joebob@aol.com");
    string fromPassword = "somePassword";
    string subject = "This is a subject line";
    string body = "Hello, ";

    var smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.freesmtpservers.com",
        Port = 587, // or 25
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", fromPassword)
    };
    using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body,
    })
    {
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.ToString().Dump();
}
```

Now obviously for passwords and what not you can use securestrings , but this is just a working example. I tested it with my own web server and smtp sent just fine.